# Update array value inside promise ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to get API data and set to localStorage(after convert image from the server to base64). When I get data from API, I create a simple loop for update image URL to base64 format but `this.users[key].picture["large"] = dataUrl;` don’t work. Because of `dataUrl` value don’t work outside of a function.
**How can I update the row object?
What can I do?**

```
this.http.get<User[]>('https://randomuser.me/api?result=100').subscribe(data => {
  this.users = data['results'];

  for (let key in this.users) {
    let value = this.users[key].picture["large"];

    this.toDataURL('//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + value)
      .then((dataUrl) => {
        console.log(dataUrl);//correct returned value
        this.users[key].picture["large"] = dataUrl;
      });
        console.log(this.users[key].picture["large"]);//not equal to dataUrl
  }

  this.storage.set('users', "");//clear
  this.storage.set('users', this.users);
  console.log(this.users);
});
```

my toDataUrl function:

```
public toDataURL(url) {
return fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  }));
```

}

Comment: What does `Because of dataUrl value don’t work outside of a function` mean? Are you sure that `toDataURL` resolves with the correct value?

Comment: I get correct  `toDataURL`  from `console`.

Comment: Is `toDataURL` accessible from the first piece of code? Also, if you log `toDataURL` before `this.users[key].picture["large"] = dataUrl;` do you see something?

Comment: @MassimilianoSartoretto Yes, I see correct return value.

Comment: I'm not sure what doesn't work then.. the assignment? Is the value lost? If so, when?

Comment: after `toDataURL`  function processing lose value `this.users[key].picture["large"]` and set default value

Comment: Of course, because it is asynchronous. The `.then(...)` block will happen after the `console.log(this.users[key].picture["large"]);//not equal to dataUrl` statement.

Comment: @MassimilianoSartoretto Okay. How can I export `dataUrl` value from asynchronous?

Comment: You cannot. Either you set the local storage values inside the `.then`, so you are sure the `this.users` value is up to date, or you write the caller in a way it expects a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call storage and persist data inside async response:

```
this.http.get<User[]>('https://randomuser.me/api?result=100').subscribe(data => {
  this.users = data['results'];

  for (let key in this.users) {
    let value = this.users[key].picture["large"];

    this.toDataURL('//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + value)
      .then((dataUrl) => {
        console.log(dataUrl);//correct returned value
        this.users[key].picture["large"] = dataUrl;
        this.storage.set('users', this.users);
  console.log(this.users);
      });
  }
});
```

Also do not do “set” “” to clear storage. Storage set method will override whatever other value you had there so there is no need to clear it this way